# Prestashop Blank Page Payment and Modules page

Tags: prestashop

I've re-uploaded fresh copy of Prestashop v1.4.0.17 many times to my hosting, but I'm getting blank page Payment and Modules page:

[image]

It is fine in my localhost. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

http://www.prestashop.com/forums/viewthread/100637/installing_prestashop/solved_payment_tab_and_modules_tab_blank_in_back_office